# Can boot be customized such that I can switch between OSes by using a hardware switch or button (no keyboard)?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub2, freenas, steam

I'm thinking of building a home-made [NAS](http://www.freenas.org/) that would double as a [Steam Machine](http://store.steampowered.com/livingroom/SteamOS/). It would have one small SSD for the operating systems and at LEAST one LARGE HDD for media, preferably a third so games/media do not have to share.

What I'd like for this is a system whereby default boot (press button, walk away) would skip GRUB2 altogether (seemingly) for faster boot times, and when I want to use it as a Steam machine, I would have to either interfere (without a keyboard, preferably) by hitting a hardware button on boot (maybe even a switch of some sort). This is because I anticipate using controllers and other periphery, the drivers for which may not work at boot time. But I don't want to sit with a keyboard and wait.

Is there a way to have this built into the machine, for the most seamless experience possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the grub timeout should have it go into into the default OS quickly, so set the timeout to 1(it's in seconds) which should allow you enough time to tap the keyboard and stop it or to let it go into Steam. Use this method: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry or you could modify the /boot/grub/grub.cfg, but that would reset every time update-grub was run.

Comment: As would your initial method; It would overwrite grub2 as well. I'm aware of this timeout method, but I was looking for a solution where grub2 doesn't even DISPLAY without (preferably) a hardware intervention. One reason for this is my anticipated use of a Steam controller, which I'm not sure if it would even work until the drivers in the OS became loaded. And since I don't want to deal with having to plug in a wireless keyboard each time, I guess I'm looking for a bit of a... hands-free solution?

Comment: Well, I see two options, hacking your controller to work like an HID so you could input keys, or setting up a switch that changes the default HDD and uses another grub which defaults to another distro.

Comment: What if I built in a switch or button that itself acted as an HID (unfamilair with the term)?

Comment: An HID is a human interface device, so if you had a device that could fake being a keyboard(Like an Arduino Leonardo) then you could have it so that it would give different inputs to grub based on switch position(switch off and it does nothing, switched on and it inputs down and return booting into another distro)

Comment: Interesting implementation, I like it. I'll look further down this avenue; Thanks!